# Get username who created/edited record in the Django table

Tags: python-3.x, django

I want to get username who created/edited records and pass this username to template in the table. I have the following code. Any suggestions how can I make this work?
Models.py

```
class Employee(ChangeloggableMixin, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    post = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = '')
    work_place = models.CharField(max_length = 150, default= '')
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Forms.py

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['name', 'post', 'work_place', 'username']

        labels = {
            'name':'name',
            'post':'Post',
            'work_place':'Work place',
            'username': 'Author of the record',
        }
```

Views.py

```
def employee_form(request, id=0):
if request.method == "GET":
    if id == 0: 
        form = EmployeeForm(user=request.user)
    else:
        employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=id)
        form = EmployeeForm(instance=employee)
    return render(request, "employee_register/employee_form.html", {'form': form})
else:
    if id == 0:
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
    else:  
        employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=id)
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST,instance= employee)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.user = request.user
        form.save()
    return redirect('/')
```

Comment: where are columns you stored it?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur actually I'm didn't get the question. I think the table(columns + rows) stored in the database. Maybe it's wrong....

Comment: please add a view file where exactly your form save

Comment: @KiranChauhan updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get user id from User model try this:

```
def employee_form(request, id=0):
if request.method == "GET":
if id == 0: 
    form = EmployeeForm(user=request.user.id)
else:
    employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=id)
    form = EmployeeForm(instance=employee)
return render(request, "employee_register/employee_form.html", {'form': form})
else:
if id == 0:
    form = EmployeeForm(request.POST, user=request.user.id)
else:  
    employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=id)
    form = EmployeeForm(request.POST,instance= employee)
if form.is_valid():

    form.instance.user = request.user.id

    form.save()
return redirect('/')
```